# Automatically update fields in polyline based on points snapped to the beginning and end

Tags: point, line, mapinfo

I have a bunch of points with unique ID's and polylines joining them. I need to update the fields on the polylines to have the ID of the point snapped to the beginning and end of each line. How can I do this in MapInfo Pro 2019?

Comment: Do you need the ID of the line beginning to go into one column and the ID of the line end to go into another? I'm assume one point can be snapped to at least two lines?

Comment: Yes that's correct.